# side affect of adding custom methods on Object.prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm adding a custom `add()` method to the Master `Object.prototype` so that all the generic objects will be able to access this `add()` method

```
Object.prototype.add = function(value1, value2) {
return value1 + value2;
};
```

Question 1 : How to check if this `add()` method is enumerable ?

I'm creating a generic object

```
var obj = {

}
```

I'm using `for-in` loop to print all the properties (this should print both own properties and prototype properties)

```
for (prop in obj){

    console.log("property is :" + prop);
}
```

This printed `//property is :add`

Question 2: Does `for-in` loop print both enumerable and non-enumerable properties?

Lets use `Object.keys` which returns an array of properties (only if enumerable)

```
var propKeys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(propKeys); //prints an empty array []
```

Question 3 : why `Object.keys` not printing the `add` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer Question 2, a `for-in` loop will iterate through a property if and only if it is enumerable, so no non-enumerable properties.

To answer Question 1, in order to check if a property is enumerable, you could actually use a `for-in` loop, something like:

```
function isEnumerable(object, property) {
    for (prop in object) {  
        if (prop === property) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The fact that your `for-in` loop prints "add" means that it is enumerable. And, in fact, all properties you define in your own code are enumerable by default.

To answer Question 3, `Object.keys()` will give you properties only if they are both enumerable and own properties. As `.add` is inherited, it won't show up using `Object.keys()`.

Hope this helps!